# How can I get CSRF-Token of a site?

Tags: python, python-requests, roblox, csrf-token

I'm trying to make a program which will automatically post trading ads on the roblox trading site https://rblx.trade. But the problem is that whenever I try to make post request, it gives an error "CsrfValidationFailed".
my current code:

```
headers = {
    "nickname": "Tortur4dVibe"
}
cookies = {"rblx-csrf-v4": data['csrf'],"rblx-sess-v1": data["rblx-sess-v1"]}

response = requests.post(RBLXTRADE_GENERATE_AUTH_TOKEN_URL, headers=headers,cookies=cookies)

print(response.text) #{"success":false,"error":{"code":"CsrfValidationFailed"}}
```

I also tried this:

```
with requests.Session() as s:
    url = 'https://rblx.trade'
    r = s.get(url,headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')

    csrfToken = soup.find('input',attrs = {'name':'csrfToken'})#['value']
    print(csrfToken) # NoneType
    print(s.cookies.get_dict()) # {}
```

API docs for the site: https://rblx.trade/docs/index.html

I tried searching it up in html in browser and using bs4 in python, also tried getting in through request.cookies and just coping cookies from my browser.

Comment: Try to look in localStorage or IndexedDB and take the values from there

Comment: I already checked for it and the best I found is "rblx-csrf-v4" and "rblx-sess-v1", which I already passed in variable cookies. But it sadly didn't help